# Out Of Memory Issue with Activator UI On Linux Server

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, out-of-memory, playframework-2.3, typesafe-activator

I'm trying to run the activator ui on a Linux server running CentOS 5.7. I have Java and activator installed, but whenever I run "activator ui" I get the following errors:

```
[ERROR] [09/15/2014 15:42:22.431] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [ActorSystem(default)] Uncaught error from thread [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
    at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:714)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.tryAddWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1672)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.deregisterWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1795)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:117)

    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.tryAddWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1672)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.deregisterWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1795)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:117)
[ERROR] [09/15/2014 15:42:22.443] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [ActorSystem(default)] Uncaught error from thread [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
    at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:714)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.tryAddWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1672)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.signalWork(ForkJoinPool.java:1966)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.externalPush(ForkJoinPool.java:1829)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.execute(ForkJoinPool.java:2955)
```

Is this just an issue that the server doesn't have enough memory, because when I run "cat /proc/meminfo" it appears there should be enough.

Comment: what is your JDK version?

Comment: @MohsenKashi java version "1.8.0_20"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the server have swap? If not then adding it might save you. Activator spawns several JVMs and they are all large because JVMs are just large. You need some headroom. Dialing down the -Xmx on the individual JVMs might help but it can only go so low before the app won't run.